# Parsing arbitrary XML in Go

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, go

I want to use Go to parse arbitrary XML and pick out specific tags. For example if we have:

```
<foo>
Hello, world.
<bar attr="true" />
</foo>
```

I want to pick out `<bar attr="true" />`, and also be able to access the "other" data as a string without having to worry about what it is. I don't want to have to define every possible XML tag the document could contain - only the ones I want to pick out.
Could someone help advise how this can be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is an xpath library, right? try this one: http://godoc.org/launchpad.net/xmlpath